# How does a scanner work with string comparison?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class teststuff {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
        String test;
        test = scan.next();

        if(test == "example"){
            System.out.println("it worked");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code, and my input is "example" even though it's exactly the same it still doesn't give me a boolean true for my if statement. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's more of an issue with the Scanner. Not the comparison operators.

Comment: No, you don't compare strings in that fashion.

Comment: I'm sure the issue is incorrectly using `==` to compare `String` contents instead of the `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
test.equals("example")
```

Because you are checking if the objects are equal, not if the object values are equal.

This is a pretty common mistake, but thankfully it has a very simple fix. :)

Comment: Haha, thank you so much. I don't know why this skipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

mainly in java we don't compare  String with == operator
since String is class we use equals method:

test.equals("");

it returns true if the two strings are equal and false if not